# Counterexample for $G$ and $H$ are graphs on the same vertex set, the degeneracy $dg(G∪H)≤dg(G)+dg(H)$

Tags: graph-theory

Prove if $G$ and $H$ are graphs on the same vertex set, then $dg(G∪H)≤dg(G)+dg(H)$

$dg(G)$ is the the minimum k such that $G$ is k-degenerate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ and $H$ be the black and red path graphs on $4$ vertices shown below on the same set of $4$ vertices.

[image: Graph on 4 vertices]

Clearly $\operatorname{dg}(G)=\operatorname{dg}(H)=1$. However, $G\cup H$ is $K_4$, the complete graph on $4$ vertices, so

$$\operatorname{dg}(G\cup H)=3>2=\operatorname{dg}(G)+\operatorname{dg}(H)\;.$$